# 'DIMENSION' type with 'assumed size array' in fortran

Tags: fortran

Dealing with old libraries and routines, I am constantly encountering following variable declarations of `DIMENSION` which causes strange behavior of the routine. And those behaviors tend to be fixed if I change `DIMENSION` into `REAL(dp)`.

```
SUBROUTINE FFT(DATA_REAL, DATA_IMAGINARY, N)

   DIMENSION :: DATA_REAL(*), DATA_IMAGINARY(*)     ! The code behaves strangely.
(*)!REAL(dp) :: DATA_REAL(*), DATA_IMAGINARY(*)     ! If I use this commented declaration instead, the code behaves just fine.

...
```

At first few times I saw them, I thought these are just some kind of small mistakes. But still I constantly encounter such declarations of `DIMENSION` with many libraries, subroutines.

So it's highly likely those were not mistakes at the time the routines were made, and the strange behaviors might stem from some changed standards or precision stuffs from old fortran to relative new fortrans (e.g. f90). But this also can be not the case because f90 is capable of treating its older brother's standard (e.g. f77) properly as far as I know.

Does anyone have idea for this kind of code's behavior?

Comment: It would help if you showed a whole scoping unit, and also how dp is being set and accessed. But my guess (which I'm 90% sure about) is that this is code depending on implicit typing so the dummy arguments are default real, while dp is a kind which is not the default - hence the problem. If you provide enough information will turn this into an answer.

Comment: @IanBush After reading your comment, it came up to me using '-r8' compile option. When the default real type set to double precision, the routine works fine without modification. It's weird I didn't try it even though I was suspecting the behaviors might be stem from some precision stuff. Anyway, thank you for giving me inspiration :)

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you have said, but if I have inspired you to use the -r8 option PLEASE STOP. I can not have such sins on my conscience. Fix the code. That will be much easier in the long run. -r8 and similar are a very unfortunate options that will just cause many more problems than they ever solve.

Comment: @IanBush Can you give me one example where '-r8' causes serious problem?

Comment: Simplest is relying on it and then having to move to another compiler which doesn't support it - your code is then broken. Further quite what does -r8 do? Does it promote, for example, constants? And whether it does or not might change from compiler version to a different compiler version. And a different compiler might have something that looks like -r8 but on careful investigation is not, and all kinds of subtle problems arise.  Nasty problems can also arise in calling code not compiled with it, e.g. libraries. Storage association can break. Just write the code correctly in the first place.